# How to deduce the expectation of a stochastic equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation, stochastic-calculus, conditional-expectation, stochastic-analysis

I am having a difficult time deducing the expectation, $\mathbb{E}[R_t]$, of the following stochastic equation:

$$dR_t = (1 - \beta R_t)dt + \sigma dB_t$$

$R_0 = r$, with $r > 0$.

Please help me with this!

Comment: It is so simple. Apply Ito's lemma $$d(e^{\beta t}R_t)=\beta e^{\beta t} R_t dt+e^{\beta t}dR_t+d[e^{\beta t},R_t]$$

Comment: The détour by $e^{\beta t}R_t$ is not needed, simply note that $$R_t=R_0+\int_0^t(1-\beta R_s)ds+\textrm{martingale}$$ hence $$E(R_t)=E(R_0)+\int_0^t(1-\beta E(R_s))ds,$$ from which the function $E(R_t)$ follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By application of Ito lemma we have
$$d(e^{\beta t}R_t)=\beta e^{\beta t}R_tdt+e^{\beta t}dR_t+\underbrace{d[{{e}^{\beta t}},{{R}_{t}}]}_{0}$$
$$d(e^{\beta t}R_t)=e^{\beta t}dt+\sigma e^{\beta t} dB_t$$
therefore
$$e^{\beta t}R_t=R_0+\frac{1}{\beta}(e^{\beta t}-1)+\sigma \int_{0}^{t}e^{\beta s}dB_s$$
In other words
$$R_t=R_0e^{-\beta t}+\frac{1}{\beta}(1-e^{-\beta t})+\sigma \int_{0}^{t}e^{-\beta (t-s)}dB_s$$
thus
$$\mathbb{E^Q}[R_t]=re^{-\beta t}+\frac{1}{\beta}(1-e^{-\beta t})$$